# How can I trim all elements in a list using Groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I need trim all elements in a list in groovy or grails? 
what is the best solution

Answer (score 21):

Assuming it is a list of strings and you want to trim each string, you can do it using the [spread operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator) (*.)

```
list = [" abc ", " xyz "]
list*.trim()
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the collect method or the spread operator to create a new list with the trimmed elements:

```
def strs = ['a', ' b', ' ']
assert strs.collect { it.trim() } == ['a', 'b', '']
assert strs*.trim() == ['a', 'b', '']
```

In those cases, the original list isn't modified.  If you want to trim the strings in place, you'll need to iterate through the list with an index:

```
for (i in 0..<strs.size()) {
    strs[i] = strs[i].trim()
}
```