# How to split and trim a sting with groovy in one line

Tags: groovy

I have a string with values sperated by the `,` char. e.g:

```
vals_str = "a, b ,    55,  val444"
```

and I would like to generate the following array:

```
vals_arr = ["a", "b", "55", "val444"]
```

How can I do it with groovy in one line?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356311/5372462)

I was able to achieve the wanted solution in two ways:

1.

```
vals_str = "a, b ,    55,  val444"
vals_arr = vals_str.split(",").collect{ it.trim() }
```

2. 

```
vals_str = "a, b ,    55,  val444"
vals_arr = vals_str.split(",")*.trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `findAll()` approach here:

```
vals_str = "a, b ,    55,  val444"
vals_arr = vals_str.findAll("[^,\\s]+")
println vals_arr  // [a, b, 55, val444]
```

Answer (score 1):

String.split could accept regex

```
def vals_str = "a, b ,    55,  val444"
def vals_arr = vals_str.split(/\s*,\s*/)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use String `tokenize()` ([source](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#tokenize(java.lang.CharSequence)))

```
assert "a, b ,    55,  val444".tokenize(", ") == ["a", "b", "55", "val444"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the way to go:

```
String res = "a, b ,    55,  val444".split( /\W+/ )
assert res.toString() == '[a, b, 55, val444]'
```